# Error in trying to add a column via a function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to practice my skills using the student grade prediction dataset by decision tree. I am trying to predict a pass/fail based on the average of the last 3 columns (G1,G2,G3), where anything above a 70% of the max score (20) is pass, otherwise, the student fails.

The code is below:

```
def define_grade(df):
    # Create a list to store the data
    grade = []

    # For each row in the column,
    for row in df['Gave']:
        if row >= (0.7 * df['Gave'].max()):
            grade.append("Pass")
        else: grade.append("Fail")   
    # Create a column from the list
    df['grade'] = grade
df.head()
```

I run it, and I have no errors. However, everytime I check, the new column 'grade' that I am expecting never shows up.

How to resolve this?

I have copied the code of someone who commented on the dataset, as they have done it before. I changed the code a little bit to fit what I have done. However, I am unsuccessful. Please help.

link to sample code is below

https://www.kaggle.com/code/samuelmjoseph/student-grade-prediction-using-decisiontree

Comment: So I just realized, that in the code that I was learning from, they used "df". which I already used as a variable for my dataframe, when I changed my variable, but kept the df in the above code. It worked. I don't exactly know how. I am trying to learn python

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something so the function is not a void

Solve it with return df inside the function and then also by calling the function in your main

```
def define_grade(df):
    # Create a list to store the data
    grade = []

    # For each row in the column,
    for row in df['Gave']:
        if row >= (0.7 * df['Gave'].max()):
            grade.append("Pass")
        else: grade.append("Fail")   
    # Create a column from the list
    df['grade'] = grade
    return df ##################ADD THIS######################
df = define_grade(df) ############# Call the function ############
df.head()
```